# About billing about map movement on Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, billing

I need to include google map in my website for assignment purpose.

I understand that charges will occur with a count of loading the map. If you move multiple markers using PanTo, PanBy, or setCenter methods, will they be charged (counted as 1 count)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using the JavaScript Maps API and creating the maps with `google.maps.Map()` then panning scrolling zooming don’t generate more loads.

You’ll be charged per map load.

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#how-usage-and-billing-work-under-the-pay-as-you-go-model)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Does it mean that there is no charge for pan and move by program in addition to pan and zoom by screen operation?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation says anything about programmatically moving the map. I think as long as you’re not creating the map again I think you may be fine.

Comment: I understand that. Thank you!!